# Voice Recording above particular Frequency for ios

Tags: xcode, ios5, avaudioplayer, voice, voice-recording

Now i'm currently working under the voice Analysis based project, In this I have to Record the voice signal which are having the frequency more than **17000** Hertz. below this rate, All the signal should be neglected. I hope there will be a voice **filter** to record this rate, If anybody having any ideas regarding this means please assist me that will be very helpful for me, Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you would like to implement a high-pass filter.

The [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter) regarding these is pretty thorough.

Where you got a voice signal with frequency components of over 17kHz is beyond me since the human voice is not even capable of producing frequencies close to 10kHz.

Answer (score -1):

Try SCListener Sample Code available [here](https://github.com/stephencelis/sc_listener).This predicts the frequency of the sound produced,and helps you to proceed further.